# Including material ui in Reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to include cdn link for my react js app. What would be the link to include material ui.
http://www.material-ui.com/#/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>First React App</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="font-style: italic;"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

    ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>My First App</h1>,
        destination);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think Material UI is available via a CDN - You'd have to install it via NPM. I suggest you check out [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) if you want a quick way to get up and running.

Answer (score 1):

The way to include material ui is through npm rather than a CDN link like traditional Frontend frameworks or libraries.

The correct way to to do it is through npm packages.

You install the library by running

```
npm install material-ui
```

Then you can use it inside your react component as below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

You can read more about it here http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation

Comment: It shouldn't be the only way.  There seems to be no way to use an AMD loader (requirejs) with material-ui.  You can do it with react and react-dom.